# Running SoapUI test cases using testRunner

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am working on a SoapUI project where I need to run my test suite using test runner. I am using external groovy scripting for environment variable. The problem I am facing here is whenever I am running test case from test runner its return Workspace as null, which is used in External groovy. So in external groovy I am getting workspace as null causing error [getProjectByname() cannot be invoked on null]. Below is the

**constructor of global script where workspace is used**

```
    AvengerAPITestManager(String TestProject, String TestSuite, String TestCase,String TestStep)              
    {
        TestName = "AvengerAPITests";
        testProject = SoapUI.getWorkspace().getProjectByName(TestProject);
        tSuite = testProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite);
        tCase = testProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite).getTestCaseByName(TestCase);
        tStepName = TestStep.toString();
        tStep=testProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite).getTestCaseByName(TestCase).getTestStepByName (TestStep);                  
    }
```

Above we have user SoapUI.getWorkspace() which is working fine when trying to run from soapUI but whever I m trying to run from testrunner SoapUI.getWorkspace comes out to be null. I even tried passing workspace like I am passing testproject name still it didnt worked.

**I tried something like this also**

```
   AvengerAPITestManager(Object workspace,String TestProject, String TestSuite, String                  TestCase, String TestStep) 
   {
        TestName = "AvengerAPITests";
        testProject = workspace.getProjectByName(TestProject);
        tSuite = testProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite);
        tCase = testProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite).getTestCaseByName(TestCase);
        tStepName = TestStep.toString();
        tStep = testProject.getTestSuiteByName(TestSuite).getTestCaseByName(TestCase).getTestStepByName(TestStep);
   }
```

In the above code I tries passing Workspace object from the test case as I passed Testcase name and all but still I m getting null for workspace. Please tell me how do I deal with the problem.

Comment: Please someone give me solution with this problem its imp....

Comment: Where do you have the global script? When you say it is not running from test runner, how do you use it? I am bit confused between SoapUI test runner and the test runner you are referring to. Can you put some emphasis on clearing my grey area?

Answer (score 1):

Here is usefull working example https://github.com/stokito/soapui-junit

You should place your `sample-soapui-project.xml` to `/src/test/resources` folder that will expose it to classpath

Comment: Please have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use soap ui in external code, try to directly create new test runner with specific project file:

```
SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
runner.setProjectFile( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" );
runner.run();
```

Or if you want to define test execution more precisely, you can use something like this:

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" ); 
TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName( "Test Suite" ); 
TestCase testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName( "Test Conversions" );

// create empty properties and run synchronously
TestRunner runner = testCase.run( new PropertiesMap(), false );
```

PS: don't forget to import soap ui classes, that you use in your code and put them to classpath.

PPS: If you need just run test cases outside the soap ui and/or automate this process, why not just use testrunner.sh/.bat for the same thing? (here is description of this way: http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help anyone out there but here is what I did to fix the problem I was having with workspace as null causing error[getProjectByname() cannot be invoked on null] When i run from cmd
try this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.project.ProjectFactoryRegistry  

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProjectFactory    

import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject    

//get the Util project 

def project = null     
def workspace = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getWorkspace();

//if running Soapui

if (workspace != null) {

 project = workspace.getProjectByName("Your Project")

}

//if running in Jenkins/Hudson

else{

 project = new WsdlProject("C:\\...\\....\\....\\-soapui-project.xml");

}

if (project.open && project.name == "Your Project") {

 def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap()    
 def testCase = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1").getTestCaseByName("TestCase");    
 if(testCase == null)

 {    

  throw new RuntimeException("Could not locate testcase 'TestCase'! ");

 } else {

// This will run everything in the selected project   
  runner = testCase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)

 }


} 
else {

 throw new RuntimeException("Could not find project ' Order Id....' !")

}
```

The above code will run everything in the selected project.